# Unrecognised database format (.accdb)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2016

I have SQL Server (in AWS RDS) where there are huge data in millions. I’m running query to get data via SSMS  in Windows server 2012. Those data needs to be analysed in Excel.

From the query results( right click then “save results as...”), I am saving the data in `.accdb` format so that this can be opened as a MS Access database. After saving that .accdb file, I’m copying those file to Window 10 ( where MS access 2016 in there).

However, after I double click on the Access file (`.accdb` format), I get an error:

> Unrecognised file format

What could be the issue? And how to fix it?
Note, in Windows server 2012 access/ms office is not installed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have MS Access installed? And now you have commented that you actually moved the file to another PC (as best as I can tell). Please update your question with all the relevant information about what you did, how you did it, and where you are doing these various actions. This shouldn't be a game of 1000 questions

Comment: Do you mean that you just gave it a file extension of accdb and expected that to produce a file compatible with access? You will just get a tab delimited file with an accdb extension

Answer (score 2):

If you want to analyze the data in Excel, just connect Excel to SQL Server.

[image]

This uses the [Power Pivot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-pivot-overview-and-learning-f9001958-7901-4caa-ad80-028a6d2432ed) engine which is the same technology powering Power BI and SQL Server Analysis Services, so it's capable of analyzing many millions of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The It’s AWS RDS DB, looks like due to security issues I’m unable to connect from my Windows 10. Still, will give another try.